# "Cannot understand what targets.Please ensure that the desired features are initialised in the catalyst.json file." issue when using ZohoCatalyst CLI

Tags: catalystbyzoho, zohocatalyst, catalystwebclienthosting, catalystcli, catalystserve

While using the Zoho Catalyst CLI to debug locally, I get an error stating "Cannot understand what targets. Please ensure that the desired features are initialised in the catalyst.json file." This issue occurs while running catalyst serve command

[image: error screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might not be in the correct folder path or you might have only initialized the project in your folder and have not pulled the code to your local system. You need to pull the code from the catalyst console to your local system to serve the same and test it. You can pull the code by using the command "[catalyst pull](https://docs.catalyst.zoho.com/en/cli/v1/pull-resources/introduction/)".